# Passing user location to MKMapItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook-graph-api, mkmapitem

I've displayed user location and i want to display those fetched locations in `MKMApItem`.
I know the way to display in `MKMapItem`..But i cant pass those fetched locations to MapItem class..can u help me in passing those values

```
FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?field=name,location,hometown"];
[ friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){
    NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

    for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data) {
        NSLog(@"%@:%@", [friend name ],[friend.location objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

and my output is:

```
2013-01-09 17:47:57.096 istb[296:1a03] Athish:Cochin, Kerala
2013-01-09 17:47:57.096 istb[296:1a03] Anges:Mumbai
.
.
.
.
2013-01-09 17:47:57.097 istb[296:1a03] Raja:Delhi
2013-01-09 17:47:57.097 istb[296:1a03] Rajesh:Canada
```

how should i pass these locations to `MKMapItem` class

```
- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender {
Class mapItemClass=[MKMapItem class];

if(mapItemClass &&[mapItemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)])
{...}}
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

I answered the question of how to do multiple geocode requests in response to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195706/multiple-locations-in-google-map-mkmapitem/14198584#14198584), so I'll refrain from repeating that narrative here.

Bottom line, I'd just suggest that you try:

```
FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?field=name,location,hometown"];
[friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    [self geocodeFriendRequestResponse:friends];
}];
```

and then you can tweak the answer provided in [Multiple Locations on Map (using MKMapItem and CLGeocoder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195706/multiple-locations-in-google-map-mkmapitem/14198584#14198584):

```
- (void)geocodeFriendRequestResponse:(NSArray *)friends
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *mapItems = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    NSOperation *finalCompletionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:nil];
    }];

    NSOperation *previousCompletionHandler = nil;

    for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in friends)
    {
        NSString *address = [friend.location objectForKey:@"name"];

        // create a block for the geocode request itself

        NSBlockOperation *geocodeRequest = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];

        // make this geo request dependent upon the completion of the prior geocode request completion block

        if (previousCompletionHandler) [geocodeRequest addDependency:previousCompletionHandler];

        // create a block for the geocode request completion block

        NSBlockOperation *geocodeCompletionHandler = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];

        // The final `openMapsWithItems` is contingent on the completion of this geocode request completion block

        [finalCompletionOperation addDependency:geocodeCompletionHandler];

        // let's initiate the geocode request

        [geocodeRequest addExecutionBlock:^{
            [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                // upon completion, we'll initiate the geocode request completion block

                [geocodeCompletionHandler addExecutionBlock:^{
                    if (error)
                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                    else if ([placemarks count] > 0)
                    {
                        CLPlacemark *geocodedPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                        MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:geocodedPlacemark.location.coordinate
                                                                       addressDictionary:geocodedPlacemark.addressDictionary];
                        MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
                        [mapItem setName:geocodedPlacemark.name];

                        [mapItems addObject:mapItem];
                    }
                }];

                [queue addOperation:geocodeCompletionHandler];
            }];
        }];

        [queue addOperation:geocodeRequest];

        previousCompletionHandler = geocodeCompletionHandler;
    }

    [queue addOperation:finalCompletionOperation];
}
```

This routine is a complicated way of ensuring that the multiple geocode requests do not happen concurrently. The logic behind this is explained in greater detail [Multiple Locations on Map (using MKMapItem and CLGeocoder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195706/multiple-locations-in-google-map-mkmapitem/14198584#14198584).

Comment: By the way, while I've tested the geocode logic, I haven't tested it in conjunction with the Facebook logic, so let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Rob-Hi Rob..I've mailed u for some queries..plz do reply me for my queries..Thanks in Advance..