# iOS mapview search locations using word

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a `UISearch` bar and `MapView`, when user types word in search bar, the MapView which contains the related places of the word should display with the `MapView` **PIN**... How can i do this.? Please help me. I have done this for single place. How can i do it to show multiple locations. I don't want `MKAnnotation`.

Comment: You say you don't want to use `MKAnnotation`. How about `MKPointAnnotation`? That's what I use to drop pins on a map.

Comment: If i say beach in india in uisearch bar the mapview should show pins in all beaches in india.. is it possible..?

Comment: IMHO, `MKPointAnnotation` is the easiest way to display a pin. What you need is the ability to search. If you were just looking for addresses, places, you could use `CLGeocoder`. If you're looking for points of interest or businesses or the like, the MapKit.framework does not yet provide that. So, if you're trying to look up general points of interest, then you might have to resort to a third party library (e.g. "Google places API") to do that lookup. It's coming to iOS, but not yet. Right now, you just have `CLGeocoder`.

Comment: is it possible by doing forward geocoding..?

Comment: For addresses, cities, etc., but not currently for points of interest. For CLGeocoding help see the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW1). If you want to look for points of interest, you might have to check out third party libraries (Google Places API?). But I'd check out `CLGeocoder` first.

Comment: do you have any example code...Please share, it will help me..

Comment: Re Third party library code samples, I'd suggest you search the web for things like "Google Places API Example". You'll get tons of hits. See [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) for information. You just need to parse the JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't see any problem for using `MKAnnotation` if you want to display multiple locations.create array of objects formed by making `lattitude-longitude pair`.Then run the loop for array and use`addAnnotations`

Refer [mkmapview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205) and [mkAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKAnnotation).

Comment: I can able to do that, here i'm using uisearch bar to get the address, if user types hospitals in india, the mapview should show the hospitals around india with the PIN

Comment: My question is how to display multiple pins using the user entered text in the search bar...

Comment: i guess you must be using ajax for getting search result on keyup of search box.so store the returned data into array of object formed by longitude-lattitude pair.and then use mkannotation or mkpointannotation to pins on your map.

Answer (score 0):

you Can Find Longitude And Latitude from Address

Go [Here](http://deviphonesdk.blog.com/?p=136)

Answer (score 0):

You asked for code samples. This is how I generally drop pins on a map:

```
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
annotation.title = title;
annotation.subtitle = subtitle;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

For simple forward geocode, I'd refer you to the [Locate Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW1). For a more complicated scenario of issuing multiple geocode requests, which (a) run asynchronously; but (b) ironically should not be concurrently with each other, I'd refer you to [Multiple Locations on Map (using MKMapItem and CLGeocoder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195706/multiple-locations-in-google-map-mkmapitem/14198584#14198584), which can easily be adapted to drop pins using the above code (rather than opening the item in the Maps app, like that other answer does).